# How can I explain the following optomechanical transmission sprectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, cavity-qed

I am considering the following ([standard optomechanical)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_optomechanics) Hamiltonian in the rotating frame:
$$H = -\Delta a^{\dagger}a + \omega_m b^{\dagger}b + g_0 * a^{\dagger}a (b + b^{\dagger})$$
for a cavity with movable end mirror. In effect, we consider two harmonic oscillators (optical oscillator $\rightarrow$ cavity, mechanical oscillator $\rightarrow$ mirror) with frequencies $\omega_0$ and $\omega_m$ and ladder operators $a, a^{\dagger}; b, b^{\dagger}$. In addition, we shine a laser on the cavity with frequency $\omega_L$, leading to a detuning $\Delta = \omega_L - \omega_0$ from the *cavity* resonance. Lastly, $\omega_m$ is the resonance frequency of the mechanical oscillator.

The cavity resonance frequency is changed due to the displacement of the mirror, such that $\omega \rightarrow \omega(\hat{x})$ with $\hat{x} = x_0(b + b^{\dagger})$. This leads to the coupling therm above. The coupling $g_0$ can be seen as the displacement of the mirror due to one photon impinging on it.

**Background**

What usually happens is that one *linearizes* the coupling by choosing $\hat{a} = \bar{a} + \delta\hat{a}$. We explicitly do *not* consider this linearized regime here, but want to explore the *strong-coupling* regime.

**Edit**

What is plotted below is the steady-state solution using QUTIP's [steady-state](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/guide/guide-steady.html) solver. To this end, we *add* decoherence rates $\gamma$ and $\kappa$, where $\gamma$ is the decay rate of the mechanical oscillator and $\kappa$ the decay rate of the optical oscillator. Writing down the Heisenberg Equations of motion, this would yield

$$\frac{d}{dt}a \propto [H, a] - \kappa a$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}b \propto [H, b] - \gamma a$$

**Question 1**

I have plotted the steady-state solution for the average photon number in the cavity, $n_C$, and the average phonon number in the mirror, $n_M$ as a function of the detuning $\Delta$. For this, I used QUTIP and obtained the following plot, with the y-axis on log scale. Here, the coupling strength $g_0$ is $g_0 = 0.3 *\omega_m$, so we have a rather weak coupling still.

[image]

This is the typical Lorentzian resonance curve. Now, we clearly see that there are peaks corresponding to $\Delta = \omega_m$, and $\Delta = 0$.
I understand the peak at $\Delta = 0$ as then there are lots of photons inside the cavity, so we have a high average photon number and thus a high effective coupling to the mirror, as $g_0 * n_a$ is large.

What I don't understand, however, is why the second peak at $+\omega_m$ is as high as the first peak. Clearly there, we have $\omega_{in} = \omega_C + \omega_m$, such that the photon - phonon scattering process is resonant. But why has it the same height?

From what I see, if we have (on average) as many phonons in the mirror at $\Delta = \omega_m$ as at $\Delta = 0$, then the effective coupling strength at both detunings should be equal. But clearly, in the former case there are less photons in the cavity, as they are not resonant with the cavity frequency?

**Question 2**

If I *increase* the coupling strength further to $g_0 = 0.6 \omega_m$, I notice two additional things:
First the resonances shift a bit to the left. I suspect that this is due to radiation pressure exerted from the photons bouncing off the mirror, is that correct?

Secondly, it seems that the spacing between the resonances is not linear anymore but slightly nonlinear. My first thought was that this is due to more photons being in the cavity at zero detuning, i.e. at $\Delta = 0$, so the shift to the cavity resonance is strongest there. Whereas at higher detunings, the shift is slighty smaller. However, I am unsure if this is correct.[image]

Comment: Are you solving for the spectrum of the Hamiltonian OR are you solving a master equation with some additional damping rates (not given in the OP)?

Comment: @Roger Vadim I am solving a master equation with additional damping rates. I will add the description accordingly.

Comment: Without the damping rates one can diagonalize the Hamiltonian by a polaron  transformation - do the lines in the last plot correspond to the exact spectrum?

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes I know about the polaron transform, but that doesn't help me. The lines in the last plot are just there to show that the resonances shift a bit from 0, 1, 2.

Comment: If the damping is small, resonances should be around the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian - identifying your resonances with these eigenvalues could help, in my opinion.

Comment: @RogerVadim The polaron transform explains the resonances, and also the shift of the frequencies to the left. That still doesn't explain why, in my first plot, the second peak of the *average phonon number* plot is equally high as the first one.

Comment: The polaron transform associates the peaks with the phonon number and the photon number - do the two equal peaks correspond to different phonon numbers?

Comment: @RogerVadim I don't understand what you mean. I haven't really dealt with the Polaron transform before, so I don't see how it connects the phonon number and the photon number?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a polaron transform - the point is that you know the exact eigenenergies of the Hamiltonian, which are labeled by the number of phonons and photons. Your peaks are located close to these eigenvalues, so you should be able to say, whether the two peaks correspond to the same phonon number.

Comment: Well if I have a second-order sideband, one might think that I have two phonons in my oscillator. But here I am plotting it as a function of detuning, and also I am plotting average numbers.

Comment: @RogerVadim So I still don't understand why my peaks have the *same* height.